# Ajax request to call json file

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to place the value of name in Employee object in my div tag his id is `#taarget`. whenever i click on my button his id is `#driver`

Here my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#driver").click(function () {
        $.ajax(ajaxoptions);
        // Ajax request sucess--
        var successpage = function (resp) {
            $("#target").html(resp.Employee[0].Name);
        };
        // Ajax request fail--
        var failurerror = function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
        };
        // create a obect to make ajax request--
        var ajaxoptions = {
            url: "EmpDetails.json",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json";
            success: successpage,
            error: failurerror
        };
    });
});
```

Here my json file.. EmpDeails.json

```
               {
                 "Employee":
                 [
                   {
                     "Name": "Amit",
                 "Designation": "Trainee",
                 "Area": "Development"
                   },
                   {
                     "Name":"Rahul",
                     "Designation": "Developer"
                     "Area":"Designing"     
                   },
                   {
                     "Name":"Sachin",
                 "Designation": "M.D"
                 "Area":"Management"
                   }
                ]
               }
```

Hey m new in jquery.. my code not running anyone can help me to make my code runable..it would be appreciate able..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You're calling `$.ajax` before you've filled in the options object, so this line:

   ```
   $.ajax(ajaxoptions);
   ```

   ...is calling the function with `undefined`. Don't make the call until *after* you've created the options object.
2. You have both a syntax error and an API error where you're making your `ajaxoptions` object:

   ```
   var ajaxoptions = {
       url: "EmpDetails.json",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json"; // <=== On this line
       success: successpage,
       error: failurerror
   };
   ```

   The syntax error is the `;` at the end (should be `,`). The API error is that since you're not sending any parameters to the page, there's no need to specify `contentType` at all. That tells the server the format of the data you're *sending* it. You're not sending the server JSON.

Here's a fairly minimal update:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#driver").click(function () {

        // Ajax request sucess--
        var successpage = function (resp) {
            $("#target").html(resp.Employee[0].Name);
        };
        // Ajax request fail--
        var failurerror = function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
        };
        // make ajax request--
        $.ajax({
            url:      "EmpDetails.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success:  successpage,
            error:    failurerror
        });
    });
});
```

A lot of people would write it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#driver").click(function () {

        // make ajax request--
        $.ajax({
            url:      "EmpDetails.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success:  function (resp) {
                $("#target").html(resp.Employee[0].Name);
            },
            error:    function (req, status, err) {
                console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But defining the functions first the way you did helps with clarity. If you're going to do that, you might consider using function *declarations* rather than expressions, so that the functions will have proper names on JavaScript engines that don't already infer function names per the upcoming ES6 spec:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#driver").click(function () {

        // Ajax request sucess--
        function successpage(resp) {
            $("#target").html(resp.Employee[0].Name);
        }
        // Ajax request fail--
        function failurerror(req, status, err) {
            console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
        }
        // make ajax request--
        $.ajax({
            url:      "EmpDetails.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success:  successpage,
            error:    failurerror
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ok sir, then tell me what code should i use.. if u can help to give code of my progaram.. it would be really helpful for me.. as m a beginner in jquery nd ajax

Comment: @Ammi: Done. You were on the right track. I don't know why you thought you should put the call at the top, but other than that you weren't far off... :-)

Comment: Sir i want to learn Ajax with jquery... can you suggest me some tutorials or something by which i can learn Ajax with jquery

Comment: @Ammi: The JSON in your question is invalid, it's missing a couple of commas. (You can use http://jsonlint.com to validate it.) With valid JSON, and assuming the element with the `id` `"driver"` isn't a *submit* button or a link, the code above works fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dghDy If `"driver"` is a submit button or a link, you can add `return false` to the end of the click handler to prevent the default action so it doesn't reload the page. (`return false` also stops propagation) I don't have specific tutorials I can refer you to, no.

Comment: @Ammi: Good deal, glad this helped!